# Tomcat [ERROR] java.io.IOException: Stream closed on uploaded file processing (Apache Commons File Upload)

Tags: java, servlets, apache-commons-fileupload

I am having an issue and I broke my head for the last 4-5 hours debugging and finally reaching out for help here. I have a simple file upload servlet that uses Apache Commons ServletFileUpload and on detecting the file, it processes the content and generates output file. The code runs fine and generates output file that I can save but on Tomcat logs, I see Stream Closed error for every request. When I run the same on Jetty in GAE, there is no Stream Closed error. Finally, I just downloaded 100 MB JBoss AS server and there are no errors for the same codebase in JBoss too. However, our client uses Tomcat and we need to resolve this for tomcat. Tested in Tomcat 7.0.59, 7.0.62 and in 7.0.82 with same error. Code and Exception are as below. Any and all help is highly appreciated.

```
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException
{
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
    FileItemIterator iter;
    String outFile = null;
        try
        {
            iter = upload.getItemIterator(req);

            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                FileItemStream item = iter.next();
                String name = item.getFieldName();
                InputStream stream = item.openStream();
                if (item.isFormField()) 
                {
                    //Log the form field names
                } 
                else 
                {
                    // File processing here.
                    System.out.println("Uploaded file field: " + name + " with file name: "
                            + item.getName());
                        try{
                        fileName = item.getName();
                        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=" + outFile);
                        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
                        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(stream));
                        processRequest(zis, out);
                        req.setAttribute("fileName", outFile);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        log.error(e,e);
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        catch (FileUploadException e)
        {
            log.error(e,e);
        }

        catch(Exception e1)
        {
            log.error(e1,e1);
        }
}

}
```

The exception line 46 refers to the statement

```
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
```

Exception Stack trace is as below.

```java
[ERROR] java.io.IOException: Stream closed
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:312)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:200)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:977)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.close(MultipartStream.java:924)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.close(MultipartStream.java:904)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl$FileItemStreamImpl.close(FileUploadBase.java:815)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.findNextItem(FileUploadBase.java:955)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.hasNext(FileUploadBase.java:1040)
    at com.ks.act.web.BWScannerServlet.doPost(BWScannerServlet.java:46)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: @Nithin Thanks for the edit, I pasted on the code but it didn't reflect for exception data.

Comment: Any help from anyone on the Stream closed error

Comment: I haven''t still figured out the answer, appreciate any help from any experts on this.